# List library and versioning: changing the content type

Tags: list, content-type, versioning

In a List library, in an item, I need to change the content type.

1.Will this be written as a new version?

2. Will an older version be shown with the relevant content type?
3. Will it preserve the values of the old content type?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the content type of an item.

- A new version is created.
- In the version history you will see the entire history. It does not show the content type directly but I presume that it is because versions are maintained as "modifications in metadata". Content type being metadata too, is recorded in version history.
- It does preserve the values of the old content type.

Note:

1. I created a item in a list with 'Item' content type and got version 1 as expected.
2. I then modified the content type to 'Task' and filled in the required metadata. The item got converted to version 2 as expected.
3. I then tried restoring version 1, to my surprise everything changes back to the way it was **except** the content type

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not changing the content type is an issue: You have to save somewhere (field?) the content type, because different content types mean different metadata